# How to call the `dir` command by Visual C++ properly?

Tags: c++, batch-file

I am trying to use the command `dir /s C:\ /b > temp.txt` in my program. I have tried it in the command line, and it always works, yet when I try it in my program, I get my program's files and folders.

[image: picture]

I am using Visual C++ and the command `system("dir /s C:\ /b > temp.txt");`. I know that something is going wrong with my program, but I don't know what.

Comment: Aside: You could implement your own programatically, with bells on: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very clear what you're asking about actually, but one thing I know for sure is that you need to escape a backslash character in a character array literal:

```
system("dir /s C:\\ /b > temp.txt");
              // ^
```

Alternatively provide a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
system(R"x(dir /s C:\ /b > temp.txt)x");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `\` is getting eaten up. You need to do:

```
system("dir /s C:\\ /b > temp.txt");
```

`\` means you're trying to use an escape character (which you don't want to do), so you have to give an extra \ to tell C (or in your case C++) that you actually want a literal .

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have said concerning the escape character, the current working directory when you are running your program from Visual Studio is most likely the directory where the project resides. There are settings in the properties under debug to change this if desired, there are also Windows API calls you can make to change the current working directory, get directory contents, etc, if you are using native C++. if using the CLR, there are other means to achieve the same thing.

using system() is probably not the best means of achieving your desired results in a real project.

While the use of the Windows API is going to result in some ugly C code, you can wrap it up into a utility library that exposes functions that use std::string.

Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx